# uninstall.dat file cannot be found in xampp

Tags: xampp

I want to uninstall xampp and reinstall with the latest version. I've recently upgraded from Win7 to Win10 which I think is causing many of my problems.

I have saved all my files and folders, so that I can insert into the new version of xampp.

After I click "uninstall" I get this message "The uninstall.dat file cannot be found and is required to uninstall the application, aborting".

There is an uninstall.dat file in xampp and it is an Adobe file. I've tried changing it to Notepad and Editpad but still get the cannot be found message. And I've tried many times without success.

Can somebody tell me how to overcome this problem?

Maybe I need to uninstall by piecemeal but I don't know how to do that.

18/02/16 - Update.

The only solution I can think of is to move the xampp folder to the recycle bin.

In that event, how could I see if any of the programs are still running, and if they are, how to delete them?

Answer (score 2):

I need to answer my own question, in case another person has the same problem. I deleted the xampp folder to the recycle bin, downloaded Version 7.0.4, installed and uninstalled, then installed once more. Everything appears to be working now. This may have been a fault with Version 7.0.2 which is what I had these problems with.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I used XAMPP nearly four years ago during my college project, now not using it anymore, so I though to uninstall it but unfortunately got this same issue, just did a simple thing to resolve the issue, I had that setup from which I installed it, so using that I reinstalled it and then did the un-installation and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste required file into xampp folder and uninstall xampp as regular procedure via control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to answer this question. I have the same issue which when the first time I install XAMPP on Windows, the process is unfinished because my laptop had problem (can be bluescreen or battery ran out). In its installation process XAMPP will setup the uninstaller, but because the process is not fully completed so it didn't have time to setup the uninstaller. I notice that I can start the Apache and MySQL from XAMPP control and run smoothly.

My solution was to rename current folder `D:\xampp` to a temporary name `D:\xampp2`, then I install the same xampp version in `D:\xampp`. After the installation of the new xampp completed, then I copied the `uninstall.exe` and `uninstall.dat` to my first xampp folder in `D:\xampp2`. After that, I changed the `D:\xampp2` to `D:\xampp` and finally run the uninstaller.